# Executing code upon creation of a javabean

Tags: java, java1.4

I'd like to execute a piece of code everytime a javabean is instantiated, which creates a variable in the bean itself. I'm using java 1.4

Comment: You should put your code in bean's constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be more descriptive.
what purpose is the bean for in the server? 
you might simply instantiate them in the constructor of the bean

```
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
private String var;
MyBean(){
 //    enter code here for intialization
 //eg. var="hi";
}
```

Comment: I was wondering why my constructor didn't work; Seems I forgot the case has to be identical to that of the bean name. Your example put me back on track. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you are describing a Constructor, however note that you don't create variables but assign values to them (in static typed languages)

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution is to change the bean's constructor to execute that code.  Or add one, if the class only currently has the default (no-args) constructor.

The constructor needs to be a no-args constructor to conform to the JavaBeans conventions.  But if the initialization depends on the values of some properties, you can always put it into the setters instead; for example:

```
public class MyBean {
    private boolean initialized;
    private String prop1, prop2;

    /* Add getters here */

    public void setProp1(String prop1) {
        this.prop1 = prop1;
        initWhenReady();
    }

    public void setProp2(String prop2) {
        this.prop2 = prop2;
        initWhenReady();
    }

    private void initWhenReady() {
        if (prop1 != null && prop2 != null && !initialized) {
            /* do initialization */
            initialized = true;
        }
    }
}
```

---

It is worth noting that some beans frameworks provide a better way to do this.  For example Spring's `InitializingBean` interface provides a callback method that is called (once) when all of the bean instances have been created and wired.  That is a good place to put initialization that depends on multiple bean properties.

Comment: If you add a constructor with args, is it still a javabean?

Comment: @chance Nof according to [the conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) but you can ofcourse also add a no-args constructor.